# Move cursor to a new line after "Send Selection to Terminal" action in Geany

Tags: ide, geany

I set in geany a key shortcut to `Send Selection to Terminal` action which send the current line (or selection) to the build-in terminal (according to: [shortcut to send selection to terminal in geany](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528367/shortcut-to-send-selection-to-terminal-in-geany?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Then I change `send_selection_unsafe=false` to `send_selection_unsafe=true` in the `geany.conf` file (according to: [Geany: *execute* line in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763292/geany-execute-line-in-terminal/763347http://))

Everything works well, I can send a line to terminal which is automatically executed. My problem is that at this point the cursor remains on the line after sending it to terminal.

Maybe I miss something, but is it possible to set or configure behaviour that cursor is automatically move to next line after using `Send Selection to Terminal` so than I can sending lines to terminal one after another (without hitting down arrow) ?

like this:

```
print("hello world!")
#I want cursor on this line after sending previous line to terminal, so this can be send to terminal immediately
```

Comment: check this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/841132/2413

Comment: Thanks, as I wrote this step I already achieved ("Then I change `send_selection_unsafe=false`..."). What I need now is moving cursor moves to next line after executing sended line, so next line can be immediately executed same way. Want the same behaviour like in `RStudio` in case of `R`.